# Vuejs how to access nested object by keys concatenated with dot in a variable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dynamic-variables

Suppose I have the following data:

```
var a = [{id: 1, name: {en: "English"},  desc: {en: "desc"}}];
```

Above array has more elements, suppose I have another component to create checkbox lists from an array, now I want to pass this array to that component with some other props like `id` key to use for id of my checkbox items, and `label` to use as the checkbox labels, The key I want to use as label for checkbox is `name.en`.
My data has the following format:

```
[{
    "name": {
        "en": "Limited Liability Company",
        "dr": "",
        "pa": ""
    },
    "description": {
        "en": "This type of business combines the pass-through taxation benefits of a partnership with the limited-liability benefits of a corporation.",
        "dr": "",
        "pa": ""
    },
    "id": 1,

},
{
    "name": {
        "en": "Corporation",
        "dr": "",
        "pa": ""
    },
    "description": {
        "en": "A corporation is a business in which a group of people acts together as a single entity; most commonly, owners of a corporation are shareholders who exchange consideration for the corporation's common stock. Incorporating a business releases owners of financial liability of business obligations; however, a corporation has unfavorable taxation rules for the owners of the business.",
        "dr": "",
        "pa": ""
    },
    "id": 2
}]
```

My checkbox component require 3 props `id, label, data`, following is my component html:

```
<div class="mb-3" v-for="(item, index) in listData" :key="index">
   <div class="checkbox-wrapper d-flex">
     <input type="checkbox" :id="item[id]" :value="item[id]" :checked="item.isChecked" @change="setValue($event, item)">
     <label :for="item[id]" class="checkbox-label-over-flow"><span>{{item[label]}}</span></label>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Now how can I access label of each item with `label` variable ? if `label = 'name.en'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how or when you are accessing the checkbox value, but the value is what you care about.  Change the value to be your label.

```
<div class="mb-3" v-for="(item, index) in listData" :key="index">
   <div class="checkbox-wrapper d-flex">
     <input type="checkbox" :id="item.id" :value="item.label" :checked="item.isChecked" @change="setValue($event, item)">
     <label :for="item[id]" class="checkbox-label-over-flow"><span>{{ item.label }}</span></label>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Also, `@change`, you are calling `setValue()` and passing `item`.  You can access `item.label` from within the `setValue()` function as well

Comment: No your solution is not working until setValue is called, it should show the label before I click. With your solution checkbox item does not have any label when rendered.